# how to make println work in main function?

Tags: scala

There are two `println` in this `test.scala`

```
case class Person(name: String, isMale: Boolean, children: Person*)
 
object For_expressive {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val lauren = Person("Lauren", false)
    val rocky = Person("Rocky", true)
    val vivian = Person("Vivian", false, lauren, rocky)
    val persons = List(lauren, rocky, vivian)
 
    //通过高阶函数的方式
    val result = persons.filter(persion => !persion.isMale).flatMap(persion =>
      persion.children.map(child => (persion.name, child.name)))
    println(result)
 
    //通过for循环的方式,其实for循环的背后是转换成filter、map类的操作
    val forResult = for(person <- persons; if !person.isMale; child <- person.children)
      yield (person.name, child.name) //yield是用在for循环中的,记录每次循环的值
    println("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
    println(forResult)
  }
}

println("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

when I run`scala test.scala`

the `println("------------")`in main print nothing,how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please put the code in the question rather than linking to it.

Comment: I just want to make my question more neat...

Comment: Have a look at the advice on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Should add the actual output and expected output.
```println("------------")in main print nothing``` is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just edited your code and got the following code and removed misspellings

```
case class Person(name: String, isMale: Boolean, children: Person*)

object For_expressive {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val lauren = Person("Lauren", false)
    val rocky = Person("Rocky", true)
    val vivian = Person("Vivian", false, lauren, rocky)
    val persons = List(lauren, rocky, vivian)

   val result = persons.filter(person => !person.isMale).flatMap(person =>
     person.children.map(child => (person.name, child.name)))
   println(result)

   val forResult = for(person <- persons; if !person.isMale; child  <-person.children)
      yield (person.name, child.name)
   println("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
   println(forResult)
  }
}
```

and removed unwanted `println("-----------------------------------------")`
statement

Now your code worked fine.

***Keep in mind that there are naming conventions for `scala` as same as for `java`***

here you must name your main source file name to `For_expressive.scala` . Here it is the object name .

When compiling the files use the below command,

`scalac For_expressive.scala`

and run the file as below

`scala For_expressive`

So you can get the expected output .